# Include prebuilt static library into shared library in Android

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

i have prebuilt static c++ library (by the way, it has size about 12.8 MB) and i want include it in shared lib.

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libMyLib.a

include $(PREBUILT-STATIC-LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := MyLib
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

it builds without errors, but libtest.so is about 34 kb. i thought it will consume MyLib.a

and this app on android takes about 76kb.

anyway, when i'm trying execute it on android, i see in the logs:

```
12-03 12:21:26.806: I/dalvikvm(8976): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.test/lib/libtest.so): Cannot load library: reloc_library[1245]:  1099 cannot locate '<some long-long string>'...
```

Comment: solved.

must be:
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -L.

the dot is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a comment: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> must be: `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -L.` the dot is important